# populate select options from json data and create a form request

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to populate a select option in form by reading the json data from url and create a url to pass on another API from the options selected to get the desired results.
How can I achieve this.

JSON Data :
https://jsonkeeper.com/b/76PF

inside a select form
select "name" store in variable "name" dynamically populated from JSON Data,
select id store in variable "id" dynamically populated from JSON Data,
click submit and send request to https://localhost/name&id

Comment: show form code .

Comment: @Swati here is the fiddle, I am not sure how to proceed on this https://jsfiddle.net/jvabh8tf/

Comment: so you need to submit values via form or ajax ? Also your url should look like this  `https://localhost/name=namevalue&id=idvalue` ?

Comment: @Swati yeah and I want to populate the options from the JSON data that in URL (https://jsonkeeper.com/b/76PF)

Comment: @Swati basically first getting the data from JSON url and populating in the select form options field and then once user selects the options , based on the selections send request to backend server https://localhost/name=namevalue&id=idvalue

Comment: still not sure its via form submit or ajax call ?

Comment: @Swati via ajax call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$("form").on("submit"..` event this will get called when submit button is clicked then use [.serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to get all inputs values as key-value pairs and then pass same inside your ajax call.

***Demo code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //this is for demo...
  var data = {
    "data": [{
      "name": "ABC-1",
      "id": 32
    }, {
      "name": "ABC-2",
      "id": 33
    }]
  }
  //uncomment below to use ..
  /* $.ajax({
    type: "GET", //change this if needed to post
    url: "https://jsonkeeper.com/b/76PF",
    success: function(data) {*/
  console.log("result will come here")
  var ids = "",
    names = "";
  //loop through datas
  $(data.data).each(function(i, val) {
    //append option 
    names += "<option>" + val.name + "</option>";
    ids += "<option>" + val.id + "</option>";
  })
  $("select[name=name]").html(names)
  $("select[name=id]").html(ids)
  /*}
  })*/

  $("form").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log($(this).serialize())
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET", //change this if needed to post
      url: "https://localhost/somename?" + $(this).serialize(), //your link
      success: function(data) {
        console.log("result will come here")

      }
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <h3>Select name</h3>
  <select name="name">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
  </select>

  <h3>Select ID</h3>
  <select name="id">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```